# LocalDateTime not working as expected in Websphere server

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, websphere, localdatetime

I have implemented LocalDateTime in java but when I run the application on two servers, it returns JSON datetime as string in liberty server, but in Websphere server the datetime was returned as object and not string. Is there a solution to this, I am having this datetime in the DB: **2001-11-12 17:18:19.123456**. Below is the code:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
private static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

@Override
public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
    synchronized (FORMATTER) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(string, FORMATTER);
    }
}

@Override
public String marshal(LocalDateTime localDateTime) throws Exception {
    synchronized (FORMATTER) {
        return localDateTime.format(FORMATTER);
    }
}
}
```

---

```
//Entity looks like this
@Column(name = "date_time")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

//The DTO looks like this
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime startDate;


//Websphere returns 
startDate: {year: 2001, monthValue: 12, month: "DECEMBER", dayOfMonth: 12, dayOfYear: .., …}

//instead of 
"2001-11-12 17:18:19.123456"
```

How can one fix this?

Comment: You have to implement `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` for the `LocalDateTime` object.

Comment: Do you use spring?

Comment: @SternK The XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation is the Jersey-specific equivalent.

Comment: @SternK No I am not using spring. Using JPA....

Comment: The problem here is that Websphere is not using defined JAXBs `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` while serializing object. The Hibernate, and JPA are not relevant to the problem. We have similar problem. Suprisingly Websphere uses defined adapter while deserializing string to LocalDateTime. 
The problem doesn't occur on Wildfly, but it does on Websphere.